# Having trouble with Compass/Sass compiling - I'm using Bones Wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress, web, css-frameworks

I'm having trouble getting some custom Compass/Sass functions to compile properly. I keep getting errors:

```
error library/scss/mixins.scss (Line 302: Invalid CSS after "...: $font-base) {": expected "}", was "   @if $targe...")
```

I was reading something on Stack Exchange about @import possibly messing it up.

Here is my function:

```
$columns: 12;
$column-width: 60px;
$gutter-width: 20px;
$max-width: $columns * ($column-width + $gutter-width);

/*********************
Variables - Fonts
*********************/
$font-base: 15px;
$font-base-line-height: 24px;

@function calc-percent($target, $container) {
  @return ($target / $container) * 100%;
}
@function em($target, $context: $font-base) {
   @if $target == 0 { @return 0 }
   @return $target / $context + 0em;
}
@function perc($width, $container-width: $max-width) {
   @return percentage($width / $container-width);
}
@function lh($amount: 1, $context: $font-base) {
   @return em($font-base-line-height * $amount, $context);
}
@mixin col($n, $padding: 0px, $border: 0px, $container-width: $max-width) {
   float: left;
   margin-right: percentage($gutter-width / $container-width);
   width:  percentage(($n * ($column-width + $gutter-width) - $gutter-width - ($padding * 2) - ($border * 2)) / $container-width);
   border-width: $border;
   padding: em($padding, $font-base) percentage($padding / $container-width);
    position: relative;
    display: inline; 
}

.wrap {
    @include col(10);
}
```

I'm working on this as I write so any help would be appreciated - I'll post the answer if I figure it out myself :)

So I've been commenting out parts of the code and using (container-width: $max-width) {} is what is causing problems. It's not liking that I'm setting the creating a variable in the function definition... don't know why?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, Awesome - I got it to work!

I'm guessing this answer will help all you Compass/Sass Web Devs out there, so I decided to elaborate a little.

I'm trying to build a responsive website for the different size devices (iPhone vertical, iPhone landscape, iPad vertical, iPad landscape etc. Anyways I broke up all my Sass stylesheets into their sizes (481up, 768up etc.).

I was trying to include my Semantic Grid system in my 768up stylesheet and it gave me the error ***"all functions must be defined at the root level"***. That is because I was importing the 768up stylesheet into my main styles.scss which breaks when you use @mixins and/or @functions in a stylesheet that is imported itself. The same problem occurs if you try to include @mixins in 768up itself, it breaks because you can't define @mixins in a stylesheet that will be imported.

**The solution!!!**

Include the Semantic grid "grid.scss" into your style.scss that is calling all the different size stylesheets via @media queries (481up, 768up), and you will be able to use the @mixins in those individual stylesheets.

Plus, even better is that none of the @mixins take up any space in the css unless you actually use them! So you could have 10,000 variables, functions, and mixins in your "grid.scss" file, and they won't bloat your stylesheet unless you use them.

I tried to include a sketch, but it didn't work. Comment on this if you'd like to see the sketch.

Well, I hope this is useful for some fellow Developer. If not, I sure learned a lot!!!